# Using a variable in jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, validation, variables

I currently validate a field by max number and it works great:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#registration" ).validate({
  rules: {
  max_number: {
  required: true,
  max: 3
    }
   }
  });
```

What I would like to do is replace the max: 3 with a variable I have already been using (available_seats).  It works fine with a number there, but when I use my variable (value of 10) it doesn't work at all.  Any suggestions?

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#registration" ).validate({
  rules: {
    max_number: {
      required: true,
      max:available_seats
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is `available_seats` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the variable to int with:

```
    parseInt(available_seats)
```